# Error installing autocomplete-python package in Atom

Tags: python, atom-editor

I was trying to install the packages to start using the Atom environment. When I create a .py file and write anything in it I get the following error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

It says: "python" is not recognized as an internal or external command,
program or executable batch file.

When I use the Windows console, I only run the python with the py command.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

I guess that's the problem but I don't know how to correct it in the package.

I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

the problem with your system python does not install so you need to install python on your system.   **download and install** phttps://www.python.org/downloads/windows/

**I check with ubuntu19.4  with python installed**

[image]

Comment: It´s installed, check the second image that I attached